# How to expand Tuple to Match Arguments Provided?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdtuple

I have a function that (after simplifying the logic) takes the form

```
std::tuple<font_heap, font_heap> get_font_heaps(std::vector<uint8_t> const& a, std::vector<uint8_t> const& b) {
    return std::make_tuple(get_font_heap_from_data(a), get_font_heap_from_data(b));
}
```

I'd like to templatize this function so that it can handle as many or as few datasets as the user passes in.

```
auto [serif, sansserif, monospace] = get_font_heaps(serif_data, sansserif_data, monospace_data);
auto [comic_sans] = get_font_heaps(comic_sans_data);
```

I've started by trying to rewrite the logic like so:

```
template<typename ... FontDatas>
auto get_font_heaps(std::vector<uint8_t> const& data, FontData&& ...datas) {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(FontDatas) == 0) {
        return std::make_tuple(get_font_heap_from_data(data));
    else {
        return std::make_tuple(get_font_heap_from_data(data), get_font_heaps(std::forward<FontDatas>(datas)...);
}
```

But obviously, even if this compiles, it doesn't *quite* do what I want: it creates a nested tuple out of this code, in the form `std::tuple<font_heap, std::tuple<font_heap, std::tuple<font_heap>>>`, whereas what I *want* is `std::tuple<font_heap, font_heap, font_heap>`

How can I rewrite this logic to do what I intend? I'm using MSVC 2017.3, so I have access to a lot of C++17 features, but not Fold Expressions (which I suspect would simplify the logic greatly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you just want

```
template <class... Data>
auto get_font_heaps(Data const&... d) {
    return std::make_tuple(get_font_heap_from_data(d)...);
}
```

That's C++14. We could even make it C++11 with an alias that discards its input:

```
template <class T>
using font_heap_t = font_heap;

template <class... Data>
std::tuple<font_heap_t<Data>...>
get_font_heaps(Data const&... d) {
    return std::make_tuple(get_font_heap_from_data(d)...);
}
```

---

[T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016045/how-to-expand-tuple-to-match-arguments-provided/46016103?noredirect=1#comment78996839_46016103) makes a good point in the comments. Since all our types are the same, we should return a `std::array` instead of a `std::tuple`:

```
template <class... Data>
std::array<font_heap, sizeof...(Data)>
get_font_heaps(Data const&... d) {
    return {{get_font_heap_from_data(d)...}};
}
```

Comment: If the types are homogeneous, I'd use a `std::array`.